# Downloading Ruby Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I typed this into the terminal: `rvm install 1.9.3` and I got this error in return:

```
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/ppreyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 
--enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml 
--with-opt-dir=/Users/ppreyer/.rvm/usr ', 
please read /Users/ppreyer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I was wondering if anybody knew the best way to fix this error?

Comment: **please read /Users/ppreyer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log**

Comment: This is a brand new computer so I don't think anything is in that file. If so how do I access this log?

Comment: Use more command like `more /Users/ppreyer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log`

Comment: @ppreyer Yes, something should be in that file. It's the log from the command you *just ran*. There's a reason it's telling you to read it. Having a new computer doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting a new machine and seems you are new to rvm, I suggest you to replace it with rbenv + ruby-build.

You will need to install homebrew that's a great tool for installing things really easily and it provides a tool that recommends you some configuration, just doing `brew doctor`, for example it says that you should install xcode command line tool, so you don't have this kind of problems.

It's lighter than rvm, and not obtrusive like rvm is, and it comes with auto-completion for your commands ;) It's really nice and I'm liking it away better than rvm.

Comment: Agree - I find rbenv great too. If you need a guide on setting up a Ruby dev environment, I wrote one here: http://astonj.com/tech/setting-up-a-ruby-dev-enviroment-on-lion/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but found a working answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467463/1536309

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements run
```

It might ask you for your password.

After that run:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-opt-dir=`brew --prefix readline` --without-tcl --without-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would a problem with clang try this

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: I actually picked this computer up today and so nothing should be in that file. I typed rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang into the file and it returned: You requested building with 'clang' but it is not in your path. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have XCode installed? You will need gcc compiler to install ruby, so ether install the latests xcode or checkout gcc installer https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: there is no need for all the xcode. There is a way to just install the command line tool