# Can't install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, homebrew

Yes, I know there's some questions posted regarding issues of installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Lion, mainly because of problems with later versions of Xcode (4.3.2 in my case).

However, I've tried all there is to try that's posted here on Stack regarding this manner, and nothing helps. It starts to compile, one minute or two passes and then suddenly halts.

As examples I've tried with the following (of course I have GCC installer installed):

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

If running **rvm install 1.9.3** the following error shows during the compilation (which halts the installation):

```
Error running 'make', please read /Users/henrikpetersson81/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here you can read the log file from the latest build fail:
http://jsfiddle.net/hyhrk/

Last thing I've tried was to follow the updated guide in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436675/937624). Same problem.

What can be the problem here?

**NOTE.** I've the following installed:

1. Ruby 1.8.7
2. Homebrew 0.7.1
3. RVM 1.17.10
4. GCC installer 4.2.1
5. Xcode 4.3.2
6. Command Line Tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RVM has an updated command to install all required libraries:

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements run
```

It might ask you for your password (for `sudo`).

After that run:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-opt-dir=`brew --prefix readline` --without-tcl --without-tk
```

---

## Update RVM 1.19+

RVM takes care of it all:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs homebrew
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are issues with readline. Since you're using Homebrew, you can try this:

```
brew install readline
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline=`brew --prefix readline`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still errors :( Here's the log: http://jsfiddle.net/srxGf/